# Gripper, system of trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have to solve a system of kinematic equations for a gripper [mechanism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCicE.png). I tried to solve this with matrices but unfortunately there are too few independent equations to substitute trygonometric functions with variables. I need an analytital solution so numerical methods are insufficient. I also did a simulation model of the mechanism and the results seem to be linear, nevertheless the nonlinearities might just not be visible with bare eye.

Unknown: $\alpha2, \alpha3, \alpha45, \alpha10$
To derive: $\alpha3(v1), \alpha45(v1)$

$v2\cos(\alpha2)+v3\cos(\alpha3)+(v4+v5)\cos(\alpha45)+v6\cos(\alpha45+\alpha6)=-v1$
$v2\sin(\alpha2)+v3\sin(\alpha3)+(v4+v5)\sin(\alpha45)+v6\sin(\alpha45+\alpha6)=v7$ 
$v2\cos(\alpha2+v5\cos(\alpha45)+v6\cos(\alpha45+\alpha6)+v8\cos(\alpha2+\alpha8)+v10\cos(\alpha10)=-v1$
$v2\sin(\alpha2+v5\sin(\alpha45)+v6\sin(\alpha45+\alpha6)+v8\sin(\alpha2+\alpha8)+v10\sin(\alpha10)=v7$

Comment: I assume you tried a substitution like $w_1=cos(\alpha2)$, $w_2=sin(\alpha2)$, $x_1=cos(\alpha3)$, $x_2=sin(\alpha3)$, $y_1=cos(\alpha45)$, $y_2=sin(\alpha45)$, $z_1=cos(\alpha10)$, $z_2=sin(\alpha10)$, and used Angle sum identities on the terms which have a trig function evaluated at a sum of two of the $\alpha$s? You'd have 8 variables and four equations. Try adjoining the equations $t_1^2+t_2^2=1$ for each $t \in \{w, x, y, z\}$, you'd then have 8 equations in 8 variables. I believe the Angle sum identities will make the four linear equations linearly independent. Should check though.